# How do i convert a single json record retrieved from firebase into an array

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to take a single record from firebase to use in vuejs but I cant find out how to convert it to an array, if thats even what i should be doing.

my mutation

```
GET_CASE(state, caseId) {
  state.caseId = caseId;
},
```

My action

```
getCase ({ commit, context }, data) {
  return axios.get('http' + data + '.json')
  .then(res => {
    const convertcase = []
      convertcase.push({ data: res.data })
    //result below of what is returned from the res.data
    console.log(convertcase)
   // commit('GET_CASE', convertcase)
  })
  .catch(e => context.error(e));
},
```

I now get the following returned to {{ myCase }}

```
[ { "data": { case_name: "Broken laptop", case_status: "live", case_summary: "This is some summary content", contact: "", createdBy: "Paul", createdDate: "2018-06-21T15:20:22.932Z", assessor: "Gould", updates: "" } } ]
```

when all i want to display is    Broken Laptop

Thanks

Comment: Can you add to your post the content of the JSON you are receiving, as well as the code of your GET_CASE mutation.

Comment: Thanks for looking, see update as to where i am currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example `let obj = {a: 1, b: 'a'); let arr = Object.values(obj) // arr = [1, 'a']`

```
async getCase ({ commit, context }, url) {
  try {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`http${url}.json`)
    commit('myMutation', Object.values(data))
  } catch (error) {
    context.error(error)
  }
}
```

But as I'm reading your post again, I think you don't want array from object. You want array with one object. So, maybe this is what you want:

```
async getCase ({ commit, context }, url) {
  try {
    let { data } = await axios.get(`http${url}.json`)
    commit('myMutation', [data])
  } catch (error) {
    context.error(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, in relation to the second one how would i then access from my component if i return through a mutation as follows  myMutation(state, theCase) {
       state.theCase = theCase;
     },   I assumed theCase.case_name but that doesnt work.   my state is theCase: []

Comment: Ok, later I will write complete example. With action, mutation, getter and component.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing thanks, sure you can tell I'm new to this and very much enjoying learning how to interact with firebase through Axios. Thanks so much for assistance

Comment: Did you get a change to work up that example for me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside / after your `.then`

```
    Object.keys(data).forEach(function(k, i) {
        console.log(k, i);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

With a response from Axios, you can get your data as:

```
res.data.case_name
res.data.case_number
....
```

Just build JavaScript object holding these properties and pass this object to your mutation. I think it is better than using an array.

```
const obj = {};
Object.assign(obj, res.data);
commit('GET_CASE', obj)
```

And in your mutation you do as follows:

```
mutations: {
  GET_CASE (state, payload) {
    for (var k in payload) {
        if (payload.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            state[k] = payload[k]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can code your store as follows:

```
state: {
    case: {},
    ...
},
getters: {
    getCase: state => {
       return state.case
    },
....
},
mutations: {
  GET_CASE (state, payload) {
    state.case = payload
  }
}
```

and you call the value of a `case` field form a component as follows:

```
const case = this.$store.getters.getCase
..... = case.case_name
```

Comment: I've again updated the answer. Can you confirm it works, I am not 100% sure this will work with Vuex state.

Comment: HI, thanks again, the first example shows the correct object if I console log the payload but how would I now get to the individual fields in my component...thanks